# Android studio, how to read the code coverage result

Tags: java, android-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

Using Android studio to run coverage test, I got this result:

[image]

For some of the class, there are tests run through all possible code path in the class, but still the result does not show 100% in either the "Method, %" or "Line, %".

How to read the coverage test result?

And it has this color code:

[image]

What do the different colors mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Colors show you if a line was executed or not:

- green: this line was executed during the test run
- yellow: this line was executed, but there might be conditions that were not triggered (i.e. `if (a && b())` and `a` was `false`, `b()` was not called)
- red: this line was not executed